# Spring RESTful controller method improvement suggestions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring, REST, and Hibernate.  That said, I've tried to put together an Enterprise-class controller method, which I plan to use as a pattern for future development.

What ways do you see that this can be improved?  I'm sure there are plenty.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) int id) {
        Session session = null;
        User user = null;

        try {
            HibernateUtil.configureSessionFactory();
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();            
            session.beginTransaction();         
            user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {    
            if (session != null) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServerErrorException();
        }

        if (user == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
        }

        return user;
    }
```

Exception:

```
ServerErrorException uses Spring's annotations to throw an HTTP 500, and the ResourceNotFoundException does the same with a 404.
```

Thanks, I appreciate any input.

Comment: I flagged this for transfer to Code Review Stack Exchange where it will get the kind of love it deserves.

Comment: Did not even know that was a thing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested Improvements:

- a) use JPA instead of plain Hibernate
- b) Let Spring inject the Hibernate Session/JPA Entity Manager
- c) Let Spring do the database Handling (Annotation (@Transactional) or programmatic (TransactionTemplate) )

Comment: * a) Do you mean use javax.persistence annotations ?

Comment: yes, and use EntiyManager instead of Session and SessionFactory.

Comment: Ok, @Ralph I have a lot of reading and testing to do.  All of this is new to me.  When I am done with what you've suggested, may I update this question for your second-review?  Thanks, Lynn