# persistence.xml not found - Gradle-Spring-MVC Project with NoSql Database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, gradle

I am creating an annotation driven Spring MVC application using Intellij 2016 and Gradle. My project structure looks like this:

[image]

I deliberately copied the `persistence.xml` into the folder `src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml` and `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`, but when executing the Gradle `bootRun` task, I get the following error:

```
11:18:40: Executing external task 'bootRun'...
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:bootRun
11:18:52.960 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ogm-jpa-tutorial
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at my.app.main.Application.main(Application.java:27)
:bootRun FAILED
```

It seems that the `bootRun` tasks is not able to pick up the `persistence.xml` from the classpath.

**Does anyone know whats behind that error and has a fix?**

EDIT for javaguy, missing init of `EntityManager`:

```
/*
Content of the class my.app.main.Application
*/
package my.app.main;

import my.app.controllers.GreetingController;
import my.app.model.Greeting;
import org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.Log;
import org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"my.app.*"})
public class Application {

    private static final Log logger = LoggerFactory.make();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TransactionManager tm = com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ogm-jpa-tutorial");

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

EDIT for Asterisk Ninja missing `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="ogm-jpa-tutorial" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- Use the Hibernate OGM provider: configuration will be transparent -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <!-- Here you will pick which NoSQL technology to use, and configure it;
                 in this example we start a local in-memory Infinispan node. -->
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="infinispan"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

EDIT, missing `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-serving-web-content'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-bom:5.0.2.Final")
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'jta', version: '1.1'

    compile group: 'org.jboss.narayana.jta', name: 'narayana-jta', version: '5.3.5.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-annotations', version: '3.5.6-Final'

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Comment: How are you loading persistence.xml ? Show the code wher you load ?

Comment: As the name suggests, `src/main/java` is for java files only. You should never put xml files (or any other non-java file) in this folder. Resources should go in `src/main/resources`

Comment: @Lance Java: Yes, as you can see, I am trying to find out how to feed the `persistence.xml` file to spring-boot. I know that this is ugly.

Comment: can you show the persistence  file code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adapting the `build.gradle` file in the following fashion:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-serving-web-content'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-bom:5.0.2.Final")
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.ogm', name: 'hibernate-ogm-infinispan', version: '5.0.2.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction', name: 'jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.narayana.jta', name: 'narayana-jta', version: '5.3.5.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss', name: 'jboss-transaction-spi', version: '7.5.0.Final'
    compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'jta', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.common', name: 'hibernate-commons-annotations', version: '5.0.1.Final'

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Comment on that:

- It seems that the `persistence.xml` was picked up correctly, but the
  `EntitiyManager` could not initialize the `<provider>HibernateOgmPersistence`  correctly

therefore the following changes were done:

- added some dependencies for the `EntitiyManager` specific for the
  MongoDB in-memory instance