# Hibernate driver not loading when using Spring Boot repackage / Nested JAR

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-boot-maven-plugin, chargebee

We are new to spring-boot:repackage. It's become a challenge to get Hibernate to initialize when packaged in a JAR.

The app starts up and runs as expected, when run from IntelliJ or mvn spring:boot run.

However, when we package the whole app into a nested Jar, the app starts up but Hibernate is unable to load the database driver.  We see the jdbc driver in the packaged jar, and the application.properties in BOOT-INFO\classes\

On startup, we see
[HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration: Did not match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPKvg.png)

Do we add a Hibernate configuration class, or how should this be handled ?
HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration

If there is documentation on this, please point me in that direction.

pom.xml for Spring Boot Jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/>
        </parent>

        <artifactId>server_spring</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>pa</groupId>
                <artifactId>server_pa</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>pa</groupId>
                <artifactId>server_hb</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>

            <plugins>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <mainClass>pa.server_spring.app.Application</mainClass>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>14</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>pa.server_spring.app.Application</mainClass>

                        <layout>JAR</layout>

                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

pom.xml  Top Level

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pa</groupId>
    <artifactId>workbench-jv</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>server-hb</module>
        <module>server-pa</module>
        <module>server-spring</module>
        <module>server_process</module>
    </modules>

    <!-->These dependencies are managed here, and can be selected (without specifying version) in modules compiled by this pom<-->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.json</artifactId>
                <version>chargebee-1.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
                <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
                <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
                <version>5.9.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.db.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>ngdbc</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.14</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.5.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>



            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.11</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-->These dependencies are automatically inherited by every module that this pom compiles<-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>workbench_jv</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/lib/
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>14</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>
                        false
                    </skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks

Comment: We would need to see some code to be able to help you. Maybe starting with pom.xml

Comment: I think we may be running into this problem.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848485/spring-boot-cannot-use-persistence    Should we continue to use persistence.xml or should we initialize the persistence unit differently ?  The jar file doesn't contain the persistence.xml file

Comment: In Spring Boot you don’t need the persistance.xml to tackle common use cases. But for that you need to include spring-boot-starter-data-jpa as a dependency. With it you should remove all the orm and hibernate related dependencies.